# PHP local variable check

Tags: php, variables, evaluation

I am working with a set of variables that i check each time a page loads.  I have successfully checked through $_REQUEST and $_SESSION, but am having trouble with the dynamci checking of variables assigned higher int he page, if they were set.

the following is my code:

```
$important_field = array('treatmentId','category','state','providerId','sellDoc','insuranceName','grossCharge','discount','allowable','patientPortion','insurancePortion','dateOfService','billFileLocation','eobFileLocation','fromTable');
foreach ($important_field as $key) {
    if (!$$key || $$key == "none" || $$key == "" || $$key == NULL) {
        if (!$_REQUEST[$key] || $_REQUEST[$key] == "" || $_REQUEST[$key] == NULL) {
            if (!$_SESSION[$key]) {
                // wow, guess it just wasn't set anywhere...
            } else {
                $user->sell->$key = $_SESSION[$key];
            }
        } else { 
            $user->sell->$key = $_REQUEST[$key]; $_SESSION[$key] = $_REQUEST[$key]; 
        }
    } else {
        $user->sell->$$key = $$key; $_SESSION[$$key] = $$key; 
    }
}
```

Apparently evaluating $$key does not seem to do what i'm looking for as it never assigns the variable to the session... how should I be evaluating the $key to get the currently set value of say, field $eobFileLocation if it was already set in the PHP prior to the check?

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

***Update:***

ok, i have the following code, but there's still one bug with it. When i follow my process through af ew of these variables are set on each page and are carried over by the session variable as expected. The issue I am still having is that when i submit a new $_REQUEST variable which SHOULD change the session variable to the new submitted value, the script is finding a local variable ... where is it pulling $key and $$key from that is finding these as a local variable?

```
$important_field = array('treatmentId','category','state','city','providerId','sellDoc','insuranceName','grossCharge','discount','allowable','patientPortion','insurancePortion','dateOfService','billFileLocation','eobFileLocation','fromTable');
foreach ($important_field as $key) {
    if (isset($$key) && !empty($$key) && $$key != "none") {
        echo "Found local variable for ".$key.", i'll set the session and user to this.<br>\n";
        $user->sell->$key = $$key;
        $_SESSION[$key] = $$key; 
    } elseif (isset($_REQUEST[$key]) && !empty($_REQUEST[$key])) {
        echo "Found submitted form  variable for ".$key.", i'll set the session and user to this.<br>\n";
        $user->sell->$key = $_REQUEST[$key];
        $_SESSION[$key] = $_REQUEST[$key]; 
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION[$key]) && !empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
        echo "Found a session variable ".$key.", i'll set the user to this.<br>\n";
        $user->sell->$key = $_SESSION[$key];
    } else {
        echo "There was no provided data for ".$key."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Any ideas why when i load the page it thinks the local (as listed above) is set? does $key and $$key read from $_SESSION['blah']/$_REQUEST['blah'] and think it's just $blah?

Comment: ok ... found the issue - though i thought i had already addressed it. apparently i reverted to old code and didnt catch it .. here's the fix .. don't use $$ everywhere, just where you want the value of the variable .. i.e. user->sell->$key = $$key ... not user->sell->$$key = $$key.

Comment: Maybe you could give a high-level introduction of what this code is supposed to do in the first place? You're checking if a variable is set locally, else if it's set in `$_REQUEST`, else if it's set in `$_SESSION`, then use the first matching value for your `$user` object?

Comment: And BTW, this seems like pretty bad data hygiene and confused data flow. If you don't know where a value is and if you have that many cases for "false", including `"none"`, you should first work on internal consistency and data management.

Comment: im working to make sure this is available mainly in the $_SESSION variable, but shoving it int o the $user just in case as well.  I ahve also changed my if statements as seen in the updated post above ... but apparently it still needs work ..

Comment: deceze - This is a custom page built to interface with PHPBB3, the $user->sell is a set of variables i've created to track sales data. I am using the SESSION to keep the data across pages as I'm not sure when $user gets cleared, though it is defined on each page based on the integration.

Comment: also, the reason for the "none" value is if the user goes back a page or two in the process and chooses not to upload one of the two files, but the session thinks it belongs there the none clears the session variable or tells me to ignore it.  hope that made sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is what you want:

```
$user->sell->$$key = $$key;
```

should it not be

```
$user->sell->$key = $$key;
```

try using the empty function:

```
if (empty($$key) || $$key == "none")
if (empty($_REQUEST[$key]))
```

and the isset function:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION[$key]))
```

Comment: I was going to say "i shortened it" ... but i guess i'll change it up a bit .. here's what i had

Answer (score 0):

it is

```
$user->sell->$key = $$key;
```

not

```
$user->sell->$$key = $$key;
```

and

```
$_SESSION[$$key]
```

should be

```
$_SESSION[$key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're messing with your variables, this is not good. In fact, using two var signs ($$) describes a "variable variable".

```
$foo = "name";
$$foo = "value";
```

So you expect the following:

```
echo $foo; // => "name"
echo $$foo; // => "value"
```

What you maybe are **not** expecting, is:

```
echo $name; // => "value"
```

So you're better off cleaning up your code first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have expressed my concerns about the cleanliness of this approach in the comments. Here's at least some more compact code without variable variables to do the same thing:

```
$keys = array('treatmentId', 'category', ...)

$values = array_filter(array_merge(
    array_intersect_key($_SESSION, array_flip($keys)),
    array_intersect_key($_REQUEST, array_flip($keys)),
    compact($keys)
), function ($v) { return $v && $v != 'none'; });

$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $values);
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $user->sell->$key = $value;
}

// For debugging purposes:
//
// $diff = array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), $values);
// if ($diff) {
//    'No values for ' . join(', ', array_keys($diff));
// }
```

Comment: hmm .. i have never even used some of the functions you're talking about there .. I'll have to read up to understand them better because i hate to copy/paste code if I don't know what it's doing... and after thinking about it, as long as i can maintain my session I'll not need the user-> values

Comment: @Silvertiger Certainly, read up on these functions! Wholesale array handling, merging and `compact`ing and *much* preferable over lots of `foreach`s and repetitive code.

Comment: I'd love to test it out, but it fails syntax check on the array_filter command. If I understood it better I'd be able to fix it.

Comment: @Silvertiger The `array_filter` callback uses PHP 5.3 syntax. In PHP 5.2-, you can replace the `function () { }` part with `create_function('$v', 'return $v && $v != "none";')`.

Comment: ugh .. it doesn't like either method

Comment: Should be fine, as long as you fix the example `$keys` array.